# How to open .bin SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, xml, datafile, files

I'm stuck and not sure if somebody had a similar issue.

I have an old database stored as `.bin` files. It dates back to 2012. I can see an **xml** catalogue file which indicates to me that it is some kind of SQL database.

Please see below:

```
<Table>
<Fields>
    <Field Name="BookID" SQLType="3" DataType="0"/>
    <Field Name="BookName" SQLType="200" DataType="3"/>
    <Field Name="ID" SQLType="3" DataType="0"/>
    <Field Name="ParagraphID" SQLType="3" DataType="0"/>
    <Field Name="TextData" SQLType="203" DataType="3"/>
</Fields>
<ConnectionStrings>
    <ConnectionString>Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Server=(local);Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=yes;</ConnectionString>
</ConnectionStrings>
<Queries>
    <Query>SELECT * FROM Docs_Pages</Query>
</Queries>
<DataKey>DataKey</DataKey>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to browse the `TextData` column?

Any recommendation for a programme that works on mac would be great. If it has to be windows is fine too, as I have a VM with Windows.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Which software created the database?

Comment: SQL server native client, so you may need Windows.

Comment: I don't think .bin is a standard SQL Server format so unless you can find some documentation or do some reverse engineering I think it is going to be difficult.

Comment: Possibly open in a hex editor, if that gives any readable clue...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions above, I don't mind if windows is needed. Just to give further info, the dataset is split into folders named as "BookID","BookName", "ID","ParagraphID"and"TextData". These folders contains multiple files mainly .bin extension but "BookID" and "ID" folders each contain the following files: "Records.bin", "Records.bin.ind", "Records.bin.inf", "Records.bin.ord".

Comment: .inf file is empty but .ord file contains the following in hex editor(not sure if useful): !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûü†°¢£§•¶ß®©™´¨≠ÆØ∞±≤≥¥µ∂∑∏π∫ªºΩæø¿¡¬√ƒ≈∆«»… ÀÃÕŒœ–—“”‘’÷◊ÿŸ⁄€‹›ﬁﬂ‡·‚„‰ÂÊÁËÈÍÎÏÌÓÔÒÚÛÙıˆ˜¯˘˙˚¸˝˛ˇ

Comment: A `.bin` file is most certainly not created by SQL Server

Comment: The XML you show is incomplete.  Also, showing the full structure of the folder would be better than telling us what they "mainly" contain.

Comment: Thanks, I just copied pasted the content of the xml file as in my post above. In terms of the contents: 1. \Docs_Pages\BookID contains (records.bin, records.bin.ind, records.bin.inf, records.bin.ord)
2. \Docs_Pages\BookID folder contains (records.bin, recordsTokens.bin, rootrecords.bin,  tokenrecords, tokenrecords.bin)
3. \Docs_Pages\ID folder contains (records.bin, records.bin.ind, records.bin.inf, records.bin.ord) and so on.. Hope this helps out